# Use puppet database variables in manifest

Tags: puppet

I am attempting to learn puppet, and so far so good.

What I am having an issue with is using a variable that I have set for a node or group in the web console.

I created a variable called myCustomSetting, and then in a manifest:

```
file {/var/tmp/myfile.txt
  ensure => file,
  content => $::myCustomSetting,
}
```

When I apply the manifest with puppet apply mytest.pp, there are no errors, but the file is empty?  What am I missing?

Comment: What webconsole is this? Puppet Dashboard? This may just apply to the `puppet master`, not `puppet apply`.

Comment: Felix, that's correct.  The puppet dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The double semi colon indicate that you wish to reach the top level scope, where you supposedly declared your variable. Check that your variable has not been declared in a local scope.